# How to handle exceptions in managed beans' getters (called from xhtml)?

Tags: jsf, exception, el, jsf-2.2

I need to handle exceptions that are thrown in beans' getters. By default, if I have a fragment in my xhtml like this one:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.someProperty}" />
```

and calling method getSomeProperty() causes an exception, the whole page is not rendered. I need to handle such exceptions globally: for some exception classes display nothing in place of this h:outputText and display the rest of the page normally. Or, at least, not render the page, but display user an appropriate message.

I've tried to resolve this problem by writing custom EL resolver:

```
package package.name;

import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ELException;
import javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver;

public class MyELResolver extends SpringBeanFacesELResolver {

    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) throws NullPointerException, PropertyNotFoundException, ELException {
        try {
            return super.getValue(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null; // TODO
        }
    }
```

Then I've registered it in faces-config.xml file this way:

```
<el-resolver>package.name.MyELResolver</el-resolver>
```

I've put two breakpoints - one in the try block and one in the catch block. When page is rendered, the try block is reached many times. But when I want to display a bean property which getter causes an exception, the catch block is not reached. Stacktrace contains fragment:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'someProperty' on type my.package.ExampleJSFBean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:98)
```

Does this mean, that another EL resolver is registered? What is the best way to handle exceptions in getter methods that are called during page rendering?

I'm using Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE and Mojara 2.2.10.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You're trying to do X, and you thought of solution Y. So you're asking about solution Y, without even mentioning X. The problem is, there might be a better solution, but we can't know that unless you describe what X is.  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem

Comment: Thank you both for this remark. I've edited my question, hope it's ok now.